# How to resolve the Rmagick installation error in windows10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-10, rmagick

**While doing bundle install**

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RMagick2.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.16.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rmagick
```

**Then I tried `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'` which in turn throwed this error**

```
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RMagick2.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

    Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

After that i tried `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib="C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.6-Q16-HDRI/lib" --with-opt-include="C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.6-Q16-HDRI/include"` which throwed the same error as mentioned above in `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'`

Please help me out with this..

Answer (score 0):

Install ImageMagick on Windows 10
Important: DON'T download the latest version of ImageMagick. It won't work with RMagick on a Windows development environment. You have to take Version: 6.7.9-9-Q16 and they have to be the 32-bit versions (even if you are on a 64-bit system). I found those versions of ImageMagick here.

STEP 1: Download and Install STATIC: ImageMagick-6.7.9-9-Q16-windows-static.exe
Set the installation path to 'C:\ImageMagick' - this is important, to avoid the common windows whitespace path bug, then just click through the rest of the installation

STEP 2: Download and Install DLL: ImageMagick-6.7.9-9-Q16-windows-dll.exe
During installation, check the checkbox to install the source headers.

Install RMagick Gem in Rails
Now go to your Rails Console (Git bash), cd to the root path of your Rails Application and enter the following command:

gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=C:/ImageMagick

The installation takes a while, when everything was successfull you should see:

Thats it. Don't forget to add gem 'RMagick' to your Gemfile.

If you still don't succeed, try to install:
MinGW Min GNU Windows Environment
http://www.mingw.org/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw...
(make sure to install the development tools)